# GAS WebApp stopped working on Chrome for iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a gsheet webapp that I use for work and I normally use Chrome to access it on my iPhone. However, it has recently stopped working. I switched to Safari for this app, but it really bugs me as I use Chrome for other things and often have to switch back and forth now.

In debugging the issue, I tried everything I could think of, and finally, I started with a stripped down webapp from the samples on Google's dev site:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Even this doesn't work. At least in Chrome on iOS it doesn't. No output, just a blank page beneath the Google disclaimer. It works fine in any other browser.

The sample app I created is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NHgzPqVKRYVDqFbHyaKS43uZewgMsFk9JQsyVnvhEe0/edit?usp=sharing

I enabled anonymous viewing on the sheet and the script, and added StackDriver logging to see if the script actually fires. It does.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT, link to code:
https://script.google.com/d/1UCblr2rR_t6spdajaK5Eh_FLQr59Tq2hrU097lhCvlJeB4HMJFEjeRRZ/edit#

More edits, here's the code:

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var q = p.getProperty('count') || 0;
  p.setProperty('count', ++q );
  var r = '* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ';
  console.log( r.substring(0,q * 2 % 40 ) + 'We\'re here! Keep trying!');
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Here we are</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { font: 14pt arial; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, World! How are you?
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about posting your code as I can't open the editor in view mode.

Comment: I have an app that transfers files from DropBox to my Google Drive and it will not work on IOS so I have to use Safari.

Comment: Check the iOS device's Chrome browser console for issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They fixed it in the latest release,
Chrome for iOS 74.0.3729.121